# Undefined Symbol for Architecture i386 "_CloseZStream", "_CreateZStream" etc

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, unity-game-engine

I have build the Unity project on my mac and it opens in XCode, it tries to build it straight away. Then it tells me it fails with 201 errors all linker errors.

Error is:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_CloseZStream", referenced from: _DeflateStream_CloseZStream_m4_604 in Bulk_System_0.o (maybe you meant: _DeflateStream_CloseZStream_m4_604)

Has anyone got any ideas on how this problem can be fixed?

Comment: Reason #216 why I dislike developing for iOS via Unity.  Something always breaks.  Are you using any third-party assets?  What are your platform build settings?

Comment: I have Run in Xcode as Debug, I have Symlink Unity libraries ticked, target SDK as Device SDK, Architecture set to Universal, scripting backend IL2CPP. Are these the platform setting you were asking? It seemed to occur once I updated Unity to latest version. I would be using some third party assets yes

Comment: "updated Unity to latest version" ah.  That sounds like it may have broken a third party asset.  I found that pretty much an update anywhere in the chain breaks everything.

Comment: Silly suggestion: delete derived data.

Comment: would you suggest to try to get rid of everything to do with the third party asset?